# SQL Injection in INSERT INTO statement with unknown number of values?

Tags: sql, sql-injection

```
INSERT INTO somedb VALUES (1, 'foo', 2020-5-14, 'somestuff', 'someotherstuff');
```

Let's say that the code above was the SQL statement that I was injecting and that I can only change the 'foo' bit, with no control over the date or the stuff after that. I could type in`');DELETE * FROM somedb;--`, but it doesn't work because I only provided 2 out of 5 values because the stuff after the malicious statement was commented out. This could be easily fixed by supplying the other values too, like this:`', 2020-5-14, 'big', 'chungus');DELETE * FROM somedb;--`

However, what if I didn't know how many values were after 'foo', or what datatype? Would an SQL injection still be possible?

Comment: I cannot tell if you're trying to hack something or want to prevent being hacked :)
This being said, any input needs to be properly sanitized / validated and then escaped before using it in an SQL statement. There are several methods for it.

Comment: SQL injection is *possible*. The effort needed to exploit it is another question.

Comment: can you please show me an example of how something bad could possibly happen? :)

Comment: As @astentx wrote, as soon as you realize that there is a vulnerability, it is only a matter of time until you figure out the right format/content of the malicious input. There is no exact answer; e.g. a too verbose error message might help the attacker to figure out the needed input faster.

Comment: Will the server become unavailable on the first error? If not, the problem is trivially solved by firing off as many variations of this statement as needed, which dedicated attackers typically do anyway to figure out the shape of the statement. Not knowing the types is easily overcome by using either `NULL`, or if it can be expected that `NULL`s are not allowed, some value that will easily convert (many database systems are very lenient when it comes to converting the empty string, for example).

Comment: You can inject, for example, some subquery or function and this way insert that data into the database, then analyse it and do what you need.